# How do I use the "else:" in my ban command? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a ban command.
I want my ban command to display a message saying that the member does not have permission to use the command.
I tried to make it, but I don't really know much about "`else:`". Can someone help me? Here is my ban command so far:

```python
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await message.channel.send(f'Banned {member.mention}')
  else:
    await message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command.")
```

Comment: `else` is only relevant with a matching `if` (or `for`, but that's a rare usage). Are you thinking of `try`/`except`, for calling a potentially exception-throwing piece of code, and then recovering from that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the error handler of a command to do so and its the advisable way to do so

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await message.channel.send(f'Banned {member.mention}')

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to use this command")
    else: raise(error)
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the Discord API, `ban()` raises the exception `Forbidden` if you don't have permission:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.ban

To catch an exception and do something with it other than raising it, use `try/except`:

```
try:
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await message.channel.send(f'Banned {member.mention}')
except Forbidden:
    await message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command.")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `else` keyword is used all of the time computer programming.

I think the best way to see how the `else` keyword works would be with some examples.

Some pseudo-code is shown below:

#### BOB'S BIRTHDAY EXAMPLE

```
if (today is Bob's birthday): 
   give Bob a cake
else:
   tell Bob, "NO CAKE FOR YOU!"
```

#### TIME OF DAY EXAMPLE

```python
if (hour < 18):
  greeting = "Good day"
else:
  greeting = "Good evening"
```

#### NUMBER EXAMPLE

```python
if x < 100:
   print("X IS LESS THAN ONE-HUNDRED")
else:
   print("X IS GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO ONE-HUNDRED")
```